# How to use try-with-resources for java.util.logging.FileHandler?

Tags: java, try-with-resources, autocloseable

I'm having below code and creating log file using `java.util.logging.FileHandler`.

In this scenario, I should manually close the resources in finally block.

```
try {
fh = new FileHandler("Test.log");
logger.addHandler(fh);
...
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  if(fh!=null) { fh.close() };
}
```

This code works. Now, I thought that it may implement `Autocloseable` interface. So, I decided to use `try-with-resources` for `FileHandler` so that the resources will be automatically closed (to remove manual job of closing the resources).

The code I tried is given below :

```
try(fh = new FileHandler("Test.log")) {
logger.addHandler(fh);
...
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But this code doesn't work.

It give an error saying that :

`The resource type FileHandler does not implement java.lang.AutoCloseable'`

- How to close the file handler automatically using try-with-resources if possible ?
- Do I need to close manually ? Or there is any other approach that I can take.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You need the handler to remain open.

Comment: Why would you add the `FileHandler` to the logger, then close it? It doesn't implement `AutoClosable`, because it's not supposed to be used like that.

Comment: And why aren't you doing this via the configuration file?

Comment: @AnishB. Oh yes there is. See the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html#close()).

Comment: Just for the record, there is actually an enhancement request to make `Handler` implement `AutoCloseable` - so probably there are use cases for this: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8025709

Comment: @SergeiPetunin even the ticket acknowledges that "use cases wherein TWR will be useful for a Handler are limited" and doesn't actually describe the situation where it would be usable, so it's a bit hard to agree on whether it's valid. I'm not sure I agree with "All classes that have `close()` should implement `AutoClosable`" argument either.

Comment: @Kayaman And it's not even possible. There is a whole raft of classes in JNDI whose `close()` doesn't throw `IOException` and so cannot be `Autoclosaeble`. Sadly enough.

Comment: @AnishB. I'm curious why you posted that misinformation without even checking. Please don't.

Comment: @user207421 i'm not sure why you mentioned  'handler remain open'. can you please elaborate little bit..i understand that when filehandler open, we should close the file. else **.lck** file created in the directory and its incomplete.

Comment: @bharathiraja The purpose of installing a log handler is to handle all future logging. If you close it straight after you install it, it can't do that, or indeed anything, except for events that get logged between the install and the close. The log manager will look after the close in due course. No intervention in that is required.

Comment: @AnishB. You haven't answered my question.

Comment: @AnishB why you deleted the post, that is useful for me. please post it. i',m trying in that way.

Comment: @bharathiraja I'm reposting the answer again for you.

Comment: @bharathiraja I have posted my answer.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne, i'm not logging application logs using `FileHandler`. my scenario is to log specific information when any exception occurs or any validation fails. say example i have a csv and i'm reading and checking whether file is valid format or  valid file name. if file name is not valid then I should write `File Name is Invalid`. and also each csv file generating a log. example `test.csv` will have `test.log` and required exception details will be there in file. For application logs I have configured log4j2 and this will have all application specific logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `FileHandler` class doesn't implement `AutoCloseable` interface.

So, you can't use `try-with-resources` on `FileHandler`.

Therefore, you have to call the `close()` method explicitly.

So, you have to go for the first approach you took.

```
public class Example {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("...");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileHandler fh = null;
        try {
            fh = new FileHandler("Test.log");
            logger.addHandler(fh);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fh != null) {
                fh.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You can try creating your own custom `Filehandler` class and implement `AutoCloseable` interface in that.

For example :

```
class CustomFileHandler implements AutoCloseable {

    private FileHandler fileHandler;

    public CustomFileHandler(FileHandler fileHandler) {
        this.setFileHandler(fileHandler);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        if (fileHandler != null) {
            fileHandler.close();
        }
    }

    public FileHandler getFileHandler() {
        return fileHandler;
    }

    private void setFileHandler(FileHandler fileHandler) {
        this.fileHandler = fileHandler;
    }

}

public class Example {

  private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("...");

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (CustomFileHandler fh = new CustomFileHandler(new FileHandler("Test.log"))) {
        logger.addHandler(fh.getFileHandler());
        ........
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
  }

}
```

Comment: @bharathiraja Now, is this ok ?

Comment: This answer, while showing the OP how to avoid a compiler error, **is an incredibly bad idea.** Closing a logging handler without removing it from the logging framework means that you've just put the logging framework into an indeterminate state. Subsequent log messages may be dropped, or may cause an application exception.

Comment: @kdgregory Please read comments in the question. OP asked for something else.

Comment: @kdgregory I have updated my answer. This is an approach not a workaround to avoid compile time error.

Comment: 1. `Autocloseable` is not a class but an interface. 2. The OP's question is pointless in a way that you haven't even identified, let alone resolved. This code will execute but it won't accomplish anything useful whatsoever.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Okay I agree. But the user who has asked the question wanted it. I think he wants to do something else with this approach (he wants to modify according to his requirements). So, I posted this answer. Otherwise, I have deleted that. Moreover, I have already edited the slight mistake for `Autocloseable` interface that I did in my answer. Sorry for writing it as class.

Comment: @All as i already explained what i need in the comments.i'm not logging application logs using FileHandler. my scenario is to log specific information when any exception occurs or any validation fails. say example i have a csv and i'm reading and checking whether file is valid format or valid file name. if file name is not valid then I should write File Name is Invalid. and also each csv file generating a log. example test.csv will have test.log and required exception details will be there in file. For application logs I have configured log4j2 and this will have all application specific logs.

Comment: @All still do you think, i shouldnt use `java.util.logging.FileHandler`.for the above scenario.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne, All,  please reply for the above comments. Your suggestions are valuable for me.